# Spel - is it possible to declare a new TokenKind value

Tags: spring-el

Spring Spel supports the following set of the TokenKind elements.

```
package org.springframework.expression.spel.standard;

/**
 * @author Andy Clement
 * @since 3.0
 */
enum TokenKind {
    // ordered by priority - operands first
    LITERAL_INT, LITERAL_LONG, LITERAL_HEXINT, LITERAL_HEXLONG, LITERAL_STRING, LITERAL_REAL, LITERAL_REAL_FLOAT, 
    LPAREN("("), RPAREN(")"), COMMA(","), IDENTIFIER,
    COLON(":"),HASH("#"),RSQUARE("]"), LSQUARE("["), 
    LCURLY("{"),RCURLY("}"),
    DOT("."), PLUS("+"), STAR("*"),  MINUS("-"), SELECT_FIRST("^["), SELECT_LAST("$["), QMARK("?"), PROJECT("!["),
    DIV("/"), GE(">="), GT(">"), LE("<="), LT("<"), EQ("=="), NE("!="),
    MOD("%"), NOT("!"), ASSIGN("="), INSTANCEOF("instanceof"), MATCHES("matches"), BETWEEN("between"),
    SELECT("?["),   POWER("^"),
    ELVIS("?:"), SAFE_NAVI("?."), BEAN_REF("@")
    ;
```

I'm wondering is it possible for us to declare a new TokenKind value and custom object which would handle the evaluation, which could be plugged into the existing Spel framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interest why you want to introduce a new `TokenKind`, if those provided just describe the SpEL DSL and play the languge tokens.

I wonder why custom `propertyAccessor`, `operatorOverloader` or `function` isn't enough for you...

Take a look into `StandardEvaluationContext` and try to find, why those hi-level hooks can't help you.